# Gitlab Runner configuration doesn't work with Docker volumes

Tags: docker, gitlab

In my Gitlab set up, I have a "runner manager" that uses **docker+machine** executor to spin up other runners with Docker installed.

The issue I have is that these newly created machines don't seem to have the volumes mounted.

Here is my **config.toml** file (notice the **volumes** sections)

```
[[runners]]
  name = "runner-manager"
  limit = 3
  url = "https://git.somedomain.com"
  id = 18
  token = "123456789"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-01-12T06:08:06Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine"
    privileged = true
    volumes = ["/root/.docker/:/root/.docker/:rw"]
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 1
    IdleScaleFactor = 0.0
    IdleCountMin = 0
    IdleTime = 1800
    volumes = ["/root/.docker/:/root/.docker/:rw"]
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "runner-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-region=us-east-1",
      "amazonec2-vpc-id=vpc-123456789",
      "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-123456789",
      "amazonec2-ami=ami-123456789",
      "amazonec2-security-group=my-sg",
      "amazonec2-instance-type=t3.large",
      "amazonec2-root-size=100",
    ]
```

When I place a new file on the "runner manager" /root/.docker/newfile.txt - the file doesn't exist in the runners.

I am missing something obvious here. I have rotated the runners after copying the /root/.docker/newfile.txt over - just in case but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an oversight from me.

What is actually going on:

- **runner manager** spins up EC2 servers and installs Docker on them. Let's call this new runner **Runner X**
- The Docker daemon inside **Runner X** tries to mount the **/root/.docker/** path, which doesn't exist on the **Runner X** server.

To fix this:

- I created a new image (AWS AMI) and added the path **/root/.docker/** (and files) in it
- When **Runner X** is now spun up, the Docker inside it can mount the volume **/root/.docker/**